# How do you transform an enhanced entity–relationship (EER) to a class diagram (UML) in workbench

Tags: uml, mysql-workbench, workbench, visual-paradigm

so everything is in the question

This is my diagram and i want it as a UML class diagram

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMjCr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you got your ERD modeled/imported in Visual Paradigm you can [generate UML class diagram from ERD](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/database-design-engineering/database-designers-guide/synchronizing-object-model-and-data-model) in few clicks.

For your existing ER model you can import to Visual Paradigm by either [reverse engineer the schema from your Database](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/database-design-engineering/database-management-guide/how-to-reverse-engineer-erd-from-database/), or [reverse engineer your schema DDL into ER model](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/database-design-engineering/database-management-guide/how-to-reverse-engineer-erd-from-ddl/).

Comment: You need to summarize the steps at least. Link only is not accepted here as answer. Also the pictures in the (at least first) link are broken.

Comment: @ThomasKilian the answer was helpful and got me to my objective so i approved it.

Comment: Is there much point in converting it like for like? Is not the point in using UML Class Models that you can express things you cannot in ERDs? Seems like an opportunity to do some thinking and improve the model. (Apologies for my abruptness here -- short of time -- can write up an answer if you want explanation)

Comment: @muszeo i'm a student and the point was for me to have the correct association in order to learn, i'm not saying it's practical for work or anything.

Comment: ok, I'm with you